# Define an array to 2 dimensional array

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
int a[2][3]={{1,2},{1,3,4}};
int b[2][3]={{4,6},{22,33,55}};

int (*comb1[4])[3]={a,b,a,b};//works
int (*comb2[4])[2][3]={a,b,a,b};//it gives me warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

Quoting http://cdecl.org/:

1.declare comb1 as array 4 of pointer to array 3 of int

2.declare comb2 as array 4 of pointer to array 2 of array 3 of int

I want to use the comb as 3dim array, where the first dimension selects the pointer of [2][3] and the rest identify the element.

This is achieved by comb1, is it possible to achieve something similar using in the inside of the declaration the [2][3]. (like what I have tried to do with comb2 without success. At the end I want to use e.g. comb2[0][0][0])

Comment: Remember that when you write the name of an array in C, it (in most contexts) decays to a pointer to its first element. So what will be the types of `a` and `b` when used as initial values in the definition of `ab`?

Comment: Did you mean "Define a pointer" in your title?

Comment: @Thomas: I want to use for example ab[0][0][0] to get the first element of a and ab[1][0][0] to get the first element of b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `comb[0][0][0]` to access the first element of `a`, and`comb[1][0][0]` to access the first element of `b`, you should use `comb1` from your question:

```
int (*comb[4])[3] = {a, b, a, b};
```

This might be confusing, since `comb` is supposed to contain pointers to `a` and `b`, which are 2x3 matrices, not arrays of 3 ints, as this declaration seems to indicate. Shouldn't the number 2 be somewhere in there?

But remember that arrays are second-class citizens in C, and in most cases they are handled not as actual arrays, but as pointers to the first element in the array. This is also true concerning pointers to arrays. In general you *don't* use pointer to array, but pointer to the first element of the array. The address would be the same, but the data types are different. Here is a simpler example:

```
float a[17]; // This is an array of 17 floats
float *p = a; // This is just a pointer to float, not to array of floats
a[0] = 3.14; // Setting the first element of a
p[0] = 3.14; // Setting the same element, through p
```

Note that there is no "17" in the declaration of p.

You *can* use a pointer to the array, but then you need an extra level of indirection, to follow that pointer and get the right data type:

```
float (*pa)[17] = &a; // Pointer to array of 17 floats
(*pa)[0] = 3.14; // Setting the first element of a, through pa
```

You *could* write `pa[0][0]` instead of `(*pa)[0]`, since `a[0]` in C is equivalent to `*a`, but that would be misleading, since it would give the impression of there being a two-dimensional array, when all you have is a pointer to a single-dimensional array.

What might be really confusing is that in the code above, `pa`, `*pa` and `a` will all be the same memory address:

```
printf("a = %p\n", (void*)a);
printf("pa = %p\n", (void*)pa);
printf("*pa = %p\n", (void*)(*pa));
```

Output when I ran it on my computer:

```
a = 0x7fff875a07e0
pa = 0x7fff875a07e0
*pa = 0x7fff875a07e0
```

Since arrays are a bit special, pointers to arrays are a bit special too. If `a` is an array, both `a` and `&a` (when used in most contexts) give the same address (but different data types). And in reverse: If `p` is a pointer to an array, both `p` and `*p` give the same address (but different data types).

In summary: If you think that since `a` is 2x3 matrix, the declaration of `comb` should somehow say both 2 and 3, and not just 3, that is misguided.

You *can* do so, if you absolutely want to, as melpomene has shown. But in that case you need to write an extra pointer indirection: `(*comb[0])[0][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want a pointer to a two-dimensional array. Your second declaration is correct (for an array of those), but your initializer is wrong: `a` and `b` are arrays, not pointers to arrays.

Fix:

```
int (*ab[4])[2][3]={&a,&b,&a,&b};
```

Comment: That way I should do ab[0][0][0][0] to access the first element. I want to get it by ab[0][0][0]

Comment: @Joe That's not what your question says.

Comment: The solution you propose creates an array of arrays of int[4][16].
What i want is a structure that has: array of pointers to int[4][16]. (which now that i read it seem to be the same)

The first declaration works exactly as I want it to work but i am not exactly sure why it happens.
Is there a way to define such a structure that would behave similarly to the first declaration (eg. ab[0][0][0]) but include the [2][3]?

Comment: @Joe "*The solution you propose creates an array of arrays*" - No, my (or rather your, because I got it from you) declaration creates an array of 4 pointers.

Comment: Indeed, but they are pointers to pointers to int[2][3] elements

What I am looking for is pointers to int[2][3] element

Comment: @Joe: No, they're not pointers to pointers to int[2][3]. They are pointers to int[2][3]. Both a and b are int[2][3], so `&a` will give you a pointer to that. The name of an array is, in most contexts, converted to a pointer to its first element, but _not_ when used as the operand of the `&` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the response, seems that i am missing something here. What you are saying is that the first way of declaring is the only way and otherwise I should use comb[0][0][0][0] instead of comb[0][0][0]? (I have also updated the question)

Comment: @Joe: I wrote a comment, but I am expanding it to an answer.